# Getting wrong weeknumber from strtotime()

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Hello my geeky fellows!

I have this list of dates:

```
20-02-2013
19-02-2013
18-02-2013
17-02-2013
16-02-2013
15-02-2013
14-02-2013
13-02-2013
```

When i use strtotime() with these dates, I get

```
Thursday
Wednesday
Tuesday
Monday
Saturday
Friday
Thursday
```

For some reason, I get thursday with todays date. Also, Sunday is missing between Saturday and Monday.

I do this

`$weekday = date('D', strtotime("20-02-2013"));`

```
echo $weekday;
```

Help, please!

Comment: Please tell us **exactly** what you are doing. `strtotime()` doesn't change a formatted date into the name of the day, now does it?

Comment: When I do echo date('d.m.Y D', strtotime('20-02-2013')); it outputs: 20.02.2013 Wed - Did you setup your timezone correct in your php.ini?

Comment: `N` would be the numeric representation of the weekday (1 for Monday, 7 for Sunday). Use `D` to get the name of the day.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I already use D.

Comment: Neither `D` nor `N` would produce `Sunday`, `Monday` etc. You are yet to post the correct code.

Comment: @ACetin `date('N')` returns a number 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday). Are you assuming the values are 0-based, like `date('w')`? Are you calculating the day name yourself from the numbers? Why don't you use `date('l')` if so? Also check the return value of `date_default_timezone_get()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your timezone is correct, this is set in php.ini or can be declared using a function:

date_default_timezone_set()

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php.

Also, here is a note taken from PHP's documentation on strtotime().

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.

Make sure you're using the right separator for the right format.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: In which Timezone is 20-02-2013 a Thursday?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out I was posting the wrong piece of code the other day. Sorry for that.

The code I used was this

`$weekDay = date("l", strtotime("20-02-13"));`

```
echo $weekDay;
```

This returned Thursday. I was not happy, because that date was Wednesday. I found out, that I had to put
20-02-2013 as parameter in `strtotime()`, and not 20-02-13.

This solved it all!